# Enable specific Graphql Method for IsEnabled=false

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I could not find anything helpful but i want to create the functionality that after the creation of a user when he first logs in he has to change his password. I thought about setting the IsEnabled Property of the UserDetails to false at creation and after changing the password to true, however, when IsEnabled is false, Spring Security does not allow access to the endpoints. Is it possible to allow one graphql Mutation to be accessible even though IsEnabled=false? Or is there a better approach to disable all Queries and Mutations to a User before he has changed his password after creation of the user?